# MDL: Set Switch state to "on" via JS

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

I can access my switch via  `let iSwitch = document.getElementById('interestedSwitch');`

I looked at github and found the method `MaterialSwitch.on()`, but `iSwitch.MaterialSwitch.on();` is undefined. `iSwitch.checked = true;` does not help either.
I am using AngularJS, if this could be a source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `interestedSwitch` is the input element with class `mdl-switch__input` you need to access the parent element. This should be the label with `mdl-js-switch` (with **MaterialSwitch** component). Then you can try something like:

```
if(parent) {
        if(parent.MaterialSwitch && parent.MaterialSwitch.checkToggleState) {
            /* update MDL state if it was changes form javascript */
            parent.MaterialSwitch.checkToggleState();
        }
    }
```