# Material designs lite: how to update checkbox value

Tags: javascript, material-design, material-design-lite

Trying to update the state of the checkbox on the UI but it seems the `componentHandler.upgradeElements` has no effect on it.

I also tried `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` and `componentHandler.upgradeElement`.

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3f3vstgq/1/)

Contrary to the slider, where `xxxx.MaterialSlider.change(newvalue);` is provided to set the state, there's nothing similar for the checkbox.

Comment: Possible duplicated:[MDL: Set Switch state to “on” via JS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36099109/2115381)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by checking the sourcecode and using the mdl wrapper rather than the input.

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/3f3vstgq/2/)

Also [reported the lack of documentation](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/4327) on their github forum.

Having the following HTML

```
<label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="demo" id="demoWrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" class="mdl-switch__input" id="demo">
</label>
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#demo').val(true);
    $('#demoWrapper').get(0).MaterialSwitch.on();
}, 1400);
```